# App.Current.Properties in Service after ActionBootCompleted

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to access a property in the App.Current.Properties[] dictionary.
However I need to do it inside a Service launched after an Intent.ActionBootCompleted.
Problem is that the Application.Current is null in this state. 
How can I access the value from there ?